# How to set a subview's frame

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

I have a view hierarchy under a `UIViewController` that consists of a main view and a few subviews of the main view, all defined in a storyboard, and all connected using IBOutlet.

I would like to set the position and size of the subviews relative to the main view.

I've tried setting them in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.  Neither work, and when called, the main view has valid frame values but the subviews all have frames of (0,0,0,0).

If I do nothing, the subviews appear exactly where positioned on the storyboard.  I need to make the following code work, but I don't know where to put it.

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(10,10,50,50);
[subView setFrame:newFrame];
```

Another way to ask this question:
Where and when do the frames of storyboard subviews get set?
Or, should I just create all the subviews with code?

Comment: The answer depends on if you are using Autolayout or not. Are you?

Answer (score 1):

when using autolayout you can set frame of the views (if the frame is calculated from super view's frame) in viewDidLayoutSubviews method or the other way I use is calling this method `[view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];` and then `[view setFrame:...];`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The position and size of subviews can be set when the UIViewController calls viewDidAppear but that causes the presentation to jump.  Setting the position and size of a UITableView in viewDid/WillLayoutSubviews does not work.